# How to get the String from msg.Payload and work with it?

Tags: mqtt, node-red

I get from a Server a MQTT Message with this Value:

```
Produktion//Arbeitsplatz_2//14416910412445//Produkt_2//
```

i must split it to get the first Value `Produktion`

But the debug only says that `Function tried to send a message of type String.`

So where is my mistake?
i try many examples, but no one works.

My Code:

```
var x = msg.payload.split("//");
var Status = {payload:x[0]};
if (Status=="Produktion"){
    var INFO = {payload:"The Production starts!"}
    return INFO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are getting that error, as you should be returning null as the if clause will never pass.

The following should work:

```
var x = msg.payload.split("//");

if (x[0]=="Produktion"){
    var INFO = {payload:"The Production starts!"}
    return INFO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in your if statement :

```
(...)
if (Status.payload == "Produktion") {
(...)
```

regards

Comment: the Status object is totally superfluous, better to just remove it entirely.